# Maven start TestNG tests from jar

Tags: java, maven, webdriver, testng

I have several TestNG tests exists in my Maven project.
Jar file created by Maven using: mvn clean package -DskipTests

How I can pass testng.xml file with defined tests to run into that jar file?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you like to package the testng.xml file into the jar file which is usually not done in the unit test area.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<suiteXmlFile>` option of [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) for this.  [This documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) details it.

Comment: could you give me example of launching test from jar file? e.g "java -jar..."

Comment: after "mvn clean install", I have several jar files created in my {.project}/target folder, also I've observed that these files do not contain test classes. Could anybody suggest me way to start my test from jar files, instead of "mvn test site" from project folder?